# Can't start service manually after `sudo systemctl disable`

Tags: services, systemctl

I have a service that starts at boot, but I want to control it manually. Everywhere I go it says `sudo systemctl disable service` should do what I need, but it seems to remove the service entirely so I can't start it manually afterwards:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/service.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/service.service.

$ sudo systemctl start service
Failed to start service.service: Unit service.service not found
```

I want to remove it from autostart but still be able to start it when I want. What am I missing?

---

> What is the output of `systemctl cat`

Before disabling it:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/service.service
[Unit]
Description=Service Name

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/service/service <username>
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: How did you enable `service.service.`? Where is located that service file?

Comment: It came with an executable that configures everything

Comment: Ok, and what is the output of `systemctl cat service.service`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon added an edit

Comment: If you use `systemctl cat service.service`  after disabling, does it show an error?

Comment: And about the output you got with that command, is not there a path before **[Unit]** text? Something like `/etc/systemd/system/service.service.`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Yes, didn't notice it. It's the same as you wrote

Comment: After disabling `systemctl cat service`: No files found for service.service

Comment: I think your service might be an alias as telcoM says or this one was removed from the system when you disabled it.  If you try to enable again, what is the output you get?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `service.service` was just an alias for the actual service name, and was represented by a symbolic link in `/etc/systemd/system/service.service`. Such links get removed when a service is disabled.

Try `grep "Alias=service.service" /etc/systemd/system/*`. If it produces a hit, the name of the file will be the actual service name, and you will be able to use that name to start, stop and re-enable the service.

Comment: I suppose should add `-r` at the end? No hits... Without `-r` it prints a bunch of "is not a directory"